# Dynamic routing in Foundation for Apps with multiple children and multiple parameters

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, zurb-foundation

I am trying to dynamic routing with Foundation for Apps, and I can't find out how to have multiple parameters in a route with a child of a child.  The route would be:

```
issues/:issueType/issueDetail/:issueId
```

and an example is:

```
issues/severe/issueDetail/123
```

In order to call one of the paths in Foundation, it would be

```
<a ui-sref="issues({issueType: 'severe'})"> Severe Issues </a>
```

My guess (which is incorrect) to call multiple children with parameters is:

```
<a ui-sref="issues({issueType: 'severe'}).issueDetail({issueId: '123'})"> Issue 123 </a>
```

Now I realize it may make more sense to call issues/issueDetail/123 rather than including the first parameter, but there could be the case where issue id's are only unique to the issue type, or there's the fact that I would want $stateParams to contain both parameters when navigating back.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a state for each route.

```
.state( 'issues', { url: '/issues' }, ...)
.state( 'issuesType', { url: '/issues/:issueType' }, ...)
.state( 'issuesDetail', { url: '/issues/:issueType/:issueId' }, ...)
```

This could be simplified further using "nested" or "abstract" states. ([Here is a video tutorial on abstract states in ui-router](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-ui-router-abstract-states))

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just using extra parameters is the better solution, thanks.